# how to solve the error "has is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get elements which contains a checked input. I got all elements using `for of` and tried this code but it gave the error `has is not a function`.

What is the problem? Please help me, thanks.

Here is my code:

```js
for (const x of allDiv) {
  if (x.has($('input').is(':checked'))){ 
    console.log(x.parentElement.textContent)
  }
}
```

Comment: `$(x).has($('input')...)`?

Answer (score 1):

`is()` returns a boolean, so your code is looking for a `true`/`false` value within `x`, which I don't believe matches your goal. The use of `for`/`of` to iterate what is presumably an Element or jQuery object is also a little suspect.

A more effective way to achieve what you require would be to select the elements directly.

```
// this assumes 'allDiv' is a jQuery object holding multiple 'div' elements
allDiv.filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery isn't as popular as it used to be, here's a vanilla JavaScript version.

Find all elements that contain children that are checked inputs:

```js
  function parentsOfCheckedInputs() {
    const parents = new Set();
    const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (const input of inputs) {
      if (input.checked) {
        parents.add(input.parentElement);
      }
    }
    // return array of DOM elements
    return [...parents];
  }
```